# Proof about a set of formulas implying two formulas

Tags: solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Here's the problem;

Suppose that $\Sigma$ is a set of formulas and $\psi$ and $\rho$ are formulas. Prove that $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\} \models \rho$ iff $\Sigma \models \psi \to \rho$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Suppose that $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\} \models \rho$. Let $v$ be any truth assignment that satisfies $\Sigma$. There are two cases:

1. Suppose that $v$ satisfies $\psi$. Then, $v$ satisfies $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\}$. So, $v$ satisfies $\rho$. That is, $v(\rho) = T$. Hence, $v(\psi \to \rho) = T$ so $v$ satisfies $\psi \to \rho$.
2. Suppose that $v$ does not satisfy $\psi$. Then, $v(\psi) = F$. That just means that $v(\psi \to \rho) = T$. So, $v$ satisfies $\psi \to \rho$.

In either case, the arbitrary nature of $v$ allows us to conclude that $\Sigma \models \psi \to \rho$.

Now, suppose that $\Sigma \models \psi \to \rho$. Let $v$ be a truth assignment that satisfies $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\}$. Then, $v$ satisfies $\Sigma$. So, $v$ satisfies $\psi \to \rho$. Since $v(\psi) = T$, it follows that $v(\rho) = T$. Since $v$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\Sigma \cup \{\psi\} \models \rho$. $\Box$

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?